# why is boolean not taking either true or false in the below code

Tags: java, android, boolean-logic

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo =
            conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    boolean isMobileConn = netInfo.isConnected();
    if(isMobileConn==true){}

}
```

i tried the above code but for some reason isMobileConn inspite of being a boolean is giving me error as unknown class.but when i tried this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo =
            conMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    boolean isMobileConn = netInfo.isConnected()==true;

}
```

its giving me no error when i AM assigning the value true to netInfo.isConnected().. which implies that it IS taking true or false in this case but not in the former..but the main objective here is to check for a particular condition so i need the first code to work... i tried keeping fianl , public and all other things to see if its going to accept the true or false as values but none of them worked.. please help

Comment: What *exact* error do you get?

Comment: I think `netInfo.isConnected()` is null.

Comment: @nem the error i got was unknown class "isMobileConn"

Comment: You cannot have `if` statements outside of a method. Put that code block inside a method such as the `onCreate` [Useful link](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/5518-common-java-mistakes.html#post18621).

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao : netInfo.isConnected is a boolean .. even according to your assumption i am supposed to get a proper result.. but that seems not to be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code like `if` conditionals need to be in a method body. For example, in your `onCreate()` method.

You can have member variable declarations with initialization in the class body. That's why the latter is syntactically ok.